# Recover a windows "Confirm Box" from Selenium::Remote::Driver package with Javascript

Tags: javascript, perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing some non-regression tests with Perl package Selenium::Remote::Driver.
I would like to recover a windows Confirm Box . I know i have to execute some Javascript snippet code to recover it. Usually, i can get a web page behaviour not include in Selenium::Remote::Driver package with some Javascript code ( Compare below ) using a selector. But in my case , i can't recover my "Confirm Box" because i can't inspect my "Confrim Box" element. SO i can't use Developer Tools to find a selector or a xpath.

PS: I don't want to know if this alert ("Confirm Box ") exists. I know it's in my web page and i don't want to assert it.

I have to use following Javascript snippet also for example:

```
   my $script = q{
       var arg1 = arguments[0];
       var elem = window.document.findElementById(arg1);
       return elem;
   };
   my $elem = $driver->execute_script($script,'myid');
   $elem->click;
```

And below part of code which contains my "Confirm Box" :

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      var promises = [];
      CW.showLoadingPanel();
      $.each(dataGrid.getSelectedRowsData(), function() { ... }
     ...
      };
```

So how can i do with this issue ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934124/1331451

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium + Perl: Check if alert exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843724/selenium-perl-check-if-alert-exists)

Comment: I don't want to assert if my "Alert Box", my "Confirm Box" exists. That's for the first post. And for the second , it doesn't concern Selenium::Remote::Driver . Thanks .

Comment: Actually yes, it does use Selenium::remote::Driver..

See "I am using perl with the Selenium::Remote::Driver module to interact with the server."

Comment: I saw it . Thanks  again

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has some convenience functions to interact with javascript alerts. In perl you can for example accept an alert with the following call:

```
$driver->accept_alert;
```

You can get the alert text with the call:

```
$driver->get_alert_text();
```

And dismiss the alert using:

```
$driver->dismiss_alert();
```

Comment: Thanks, but how for example can i click on an ok Button in my "Confirm Box"(Alert) ?

Comment: `$driver->accept_alert;` Will press the Ok button (doesn't matter what the name is) in an alert, yes.

Comment: Thanks. I will tell you if it's ok here .

Comment: Yes thanks . I just have to do something before. But it seems to be able to work. I keep you informed

Comment: I did this work on standby because i have an other issue immediatly before. Be sure i will give you the result , working or not. Thanks for reply

Comment: It works with :    $driver-> accept_alert; And not with "get_alert_text;". Thanks again

Comment: Well yes, of course get_alert_text doesn't work to accept an alert.